# Why does having [].map with curly brackets change the way it works?

Tags: javascript

So, basically I have this:

```
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
    return ("[" + this.map(thing => thing = '"' + thing + '"').join(', ') + "]")
}
```

When I call it:

```
['foo', 'bar'].toString()
```

It returns

> "["foo", "bar"]"

Now, THAT would work perfectly. This one (with curly brackets) doesn't seem to work like I wanted it to:

```
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
    return ("[" + this.map(thing => {thing = '"' + thing + '"'}).join(', ') + "]")
}
```

and it returns:

> [, ]

So can someone tell me the difference? I don't know why [].map works like this.

Comment: If you don't believe me, try doing it into the Chrome browser console.

Comment: When using curly braces, you have to use `return` otherwise the result will just be undefined.

Comment: why the assignment inside of the second one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with arrays or the map method. It is entirely about how arrow functions work.

When you give a single statement on the right hand side, then that statement is evaluated and returned inside the function.

```
foo => bar
```

is equivalent to:

```
function (foo) { return bar; }
```

When you put a block on the right hand side, that block simply because the function body.

```
foo => { bar }
```

is equivalent to:

```
function (foo) { bar; }
```

In this second version, you have no `return` statement, so the function returns `undefined`.

You need to make the return statement explicit if you use a block.

```
foo => { return bar; }
```

Comment: I don't know if I should mark this one as my answer or Rhumborl's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You do not return something in the block statement of the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
() => {
    // code
    return 42; // return is required in block statment
}


() => 42 // return is implicit
```

```js
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
    return ("[" + this.map(thing => { return thing = '"' + thing + '"'}).join(', ') + "]")
};

console.log(['foo', 'bar'].toString())
```

Shorter, without assignment to `thing`

```js
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
    return ("[" + this.map(thing => '"' + thing + '"').join(', ') + "]")
};

console.log(['foo', 'bar'].toString())
```

Comment: If he want to use impliced return, he should get rid of brackets and put everything in one line as he did.

Answer (score 0):

Without curly braces (or with regular curved brackets) it returns a single value straight up, whereas curly braces execute multiple lines of code. If you want this code to return a value you have to explicitly return it within those curly braces.

Comment: basically, i have to add a return statement?

Comment: Yes. You can have as much code inside the curly braces as you want, but at the end you gotta return something

Comment: @DaDerpFace that's one option, the second is get rid of the code block brackets and still keep whole expression in one line, so then `return` keyoword would be impliced - this works only with arrow functions in ES2015

Answer (score 0):

Because when you add `{}`, it turns it from a pure functional-style arrow function into a normal function, just it has arrow syntax. If you want to return a value from this, you need to explicitly write `return thing;` at the end:

```
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
    return ("[" + this.map(thing => {thing = '"' + thing + '"'; return thing;}).join(', ') + "]")
}
```

The reason the pure arrow function works is because the statement `thing = '"' + thing + '"'` actually returns the result, and hence is the return value of the function. You could get exactly the same result without reassigning `thing`:

```
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
    return ("[" + this.map(thing => '"' + thing + '"').join(', ') + "]")
}
```

Comment: `() => {}` is stil an arrow function with all features of an arrow fuction without *automatic* return of the expression.