# Undefined value after RxJs mapping

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs, reactive-programming

Why am I getting undefined inside subscribe method? 
I am trying to combine to data sources. Customers and Categories. 
I am trying to fill Category property of customer based on matching CategoryId from Category collection.

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-deborahk)

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    const custurmersWithCategory$ = combineLatest([
      this.http
        .get<ICustomer[]>(
          "https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cgqEBPcHtu?indent=4"
        )
        .pipe(delay(1000)),
      this.http.get<ICategory[]>(
        "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5db4195d300000520057b70b"
      )
    ]).pipe(
       map(([customers, categories]) => {
         customers.map(
          customer =>
            ({
              ...customer,
              Category: categories.find(
                c => customer.CategoryId === c.CategoryId
              ).category
            } as ICustomer)
        );
      })
    );

    custurmersWithCategory$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);// why is this undefined?
    });
  }
```

Comment: you aren't returning anything from `map`...

Comment: @AJT82 I am new to JS world so please bear with me. I thought rxjs `map` is like a filter that will change the values that passes through it. What exactly am I supposed to to return here? I wrote `return customers` at the end of the map block but it did not map the customer property.

Comment: You are using curly brackets `{ customers.map(...` so you need to do `{ return customers.map(...` : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-deborahk-64z2cg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742934/why-does-having-map-with-curly-brackets-change-the-way-it-works

Comment: @AJT82 you should post it as an answer. Btw,  customers.map creates and returns a new object? Instead of mutating the customers itself?

Comment: Yes, it returns a new object :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't currently returning anything from `map`, thus you get `undefined`. As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41743119/6294072 your code translates to something like:

```
function (foo) { bar; }
```

which doesn't return anything at all. So add

```
return customers.map( ...
```

and it will actually return some values.

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-deborahk-64z2cg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

As per comment if not wanting to add the `return`, you can just remove the curly brackets from inside `map`.

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-deborahk-du2hen?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

As a further comment, like mentioned in the answer I linked, this has nothing to do with rxjs `map`, but rather how arrow functions work :)

Comment: @ how would you write it without curly braces? I removed `return` keyword from your script along with the curly braces and it didn't work

Comment: I think it's working like it should when removing brackets? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-deborahk-du2hen?file=src/app/app.component.ts or am I missing something :)

Comment: I forgot to take out the `;` along with braces. JS syntax drives me crazy.

Comment: Haha :D Yeah, well as you know there's the learning curve for everything. I know the feeling when you go nutters when learning something new that doesn't perhaps resemble the programming language(s) you've used before. Slow and painful in the beginning :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` your map function.

```
return customers.map(...
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `return`

```
   return customers.map(
      customer =>
        ({
          ...customer,
          Category: categories.find(
            c => customer.CategoryId === c.CategoryId
          ).category
        } as ICustomer)
    );
```