# undefined outcome with spread operator

Tags: javascript, typescript

What am I doing wrong in my little code snippet that I get `undefined` instead of `number` outcome?

```
function multiply(multiplier: number, ...args: [number, number, number]) {
    return args.map(
        element => { multiplier * element; }
    );
}

console.log(multiply(2, 5,6,7));
```

output: `[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]`

Comment: `element =>  multiplier * element;` or `element => { return multiplier * element; }`

Comment: Thank you so much. It fixed it. If you put your comment as an answer, I will mark it as answer.

Comment: Nah, feel free to delete

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment by mplungjan, I realized I should modify the content of my `map` function as follows:

```
element => { return multiplier * element; }
```

Comment: No need to answer. Plenty of dupes [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742934/why-does-having-map-with-curly-brackets-change-the-way-it-works)